# Easy way to substring without fear of exceeding the string boundaries?

Tags: c#, .net

I am now taking parts of string like this:

```
something.Substring(0, something.Length >= 8 ? 8 : something.Length)
```

The only reason for that extra mess is because sometimes the length is smaller than what I put in the method parameter and this causes an error.

Is there a simpler way to crop text *safely*?

Comment: AFAIK not in the framework, but it should be trivial to write such a method yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tiny way to get the first 25 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595004/tiny-way-to-get-the-first-25-characters)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write an extension method on `string` that hides the "mess" away.

```
public static string SafeSubstring(this string orig, int length)
{
  return orig.Substring(0, orig.Length >= length ? length : orig.Length);
}

something.SafeSubstring(8);
```

Answer (score 21):

There's really no need for an ugly ternary expression here.

```
return something.Substring(0, Math.Min(length, something.Length));
```

Answer (score 3):

Visual Basic implements Right() and Left() string functions.  Might as well steal them, they have been well tested:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static string Right(this string str, int Length) {
        if (Length < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Length");
        if (Length == 0 || str == null) return string.Empty;
        int len = str.Length;
        if (Length >= len) return str;
        else return str.Substring(len - Length, Length);
    }
    public static string Left(this string str, int Length)
    {
        if (Length < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Length");
        if (Length == 0 || str == null) return string.Empty;
        int len = str.Length;
        if (Length >= len) return str;
        else return str.Substring(0, Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: OP's question appears to need the equivalent of Left(), rather than Right().  edited this answer to include Left()

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the most effective way to do this, and I would go with Oded's solution, but this is also a way to achieve what you're looking for:

```
new string(something.Take(8).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

I would expand upon [Oded's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded) extension to include the starting index.

```
public static string SafeSubstring(this string orig, int start, int length)
{
    if (start >= orig.Length) return string.Empty; // could return orig or null
    return orig.Substring(start, orig.Length >= start + length ? length : orig.Length - start);
}

// Then you can call it the same as you would Substring.    
var newString = aString.SafeSubstring(3, 8);
```

Comment: Or, one could just use the `.Right(count)` function on the string, to get the rightmost count characters in a safe way. If 0, it returns an empty string. If > length, it returns the whole string. Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.right?view=net-7.0

Comment: @dodexahedron As long as your needed part of the string starts at index 0, then .Right(count) works. But if you need to start after index 0, this method works.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [Hans Passant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10864985/1633949), here's a more direct way to "steal" the Visual Basic implementation. (*This approach requires adding a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll*)

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string Right(this string str, int Length) =>
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Right(str, Length);

    public static string Left(this string str, int Length) =>
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Left(str, Length);
}
```