# Linq search - Display small part of searched text

Tags: linq, search, text, replace

I'm trying to implement text search with linq. I have a Messages table which is populated with emails data. I want to be able to search in Messages body. However emails bodies are very long and I will like to display only small part of the searched text for example if I search for:

**aute**

in the following text:

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.*

the result should be:

*...aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis **aute** irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur....*

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

```
var query = from str in messages
  let index = str.IndexOf(search)
  where index > -1
  select str.Substring(Math.Max(0, index - radius), radius + Math.Min(radius, str.Length - index));
```

Where messages is your email string list, and radius is an int describing how many characters you want to take before and after the string you are looking for. Note that this code will only return the first match in every email, ignoring the other ones.

Everything would be easier if you could use an helper function to calculate the proper substring tho.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595004/tiny-way-to-get-the-first-25-characters) you can find an extension method that implements a safe version of string.substring, making hte above linq code look something like:

```
var query = from str in lst
  let index = str.IndexOf(search)
  where index > -1
  select str.SafeSubstring(index - radius, 2*radius);
```

that in my opinion is much simnpler to read

**EDIT**

Extending string with the two following methods :

```
    public static List<int> IndexOfAll(this String str, string search)
    {
        List<int> lst = new List<int>();
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(str,search))
        {
            lst.Add(match.Index);
        }
        return lst;
    }

    public static string SafeSubstring(this String str, int start, int n)
    {
        return str.Substring(Math.Max(start, 0), Math.Min(n, str.Length - start));
    }
```

you can get all the results in a nice form, using

```
var query = from str in lst
  let index = str.IndexOfAll(search)
  where index.Count>0
  select index.Select(x => str.SafeSubstring(x-radius, 2*radius));
```

with query as an IEnumerable

Comment: i figured it out. Thanks for your help.